# Get mobile numbers and passwords from a string

Tags: java, regex

What regular expression should I use in order to get mobile numbers from strings like the following example?

What regular expression should I use to get meeting passwords from strings like the following example?

```
MTW-08 Party-Bridge25 - PH: +91-80-30912334 
+91-80-43452300 Extn: 11200; Meeting ID - 882004 ; 
Meeting Password – 1234
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You provided only two examples, and I'm not sure if all numbers in you real data follows the same format. But if they are, following regexp will match to these numbers:

```
(\+\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{8})
```

Where:

- `\d` matches to any digit (0-9)
- `{2}` specifies how many times digit must be repeated, it this case - 2

You can also match only numbers which starts with *+91* prefix using this regexp:

```
(\+91-\d{2}-\d{8})
```

Comment: {2} will be like 2 numbers? and first 2 should definately be 91

Comment: Exactly, `\d` matches to any digit, and `{n}` tells how many times previous character or group should be repeated.

Comment: so can i put it like this (\+91\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{8}) if +91 is mandatory in the beginning?

Comment: Not exactly, it should be `(\+91-\d{2}-\d{8})` (first `\d{2}-` should be removed).

Comment: can i put a string like(\Meeting Password-\d{4}) or do i need to equals for string and then use regex for getting passcode?

Comment: You can but without this backslash after `(`: `(Meeting Password-\d{4})`. Try to use [Regex101](https://regex101.com/) to test your regular expressions, it will show you also what particular parts of regexp do.

Comment: I'm afraid that this conversation is turning into offtopic... Here is a working regexp for meeting passwords:  `(Meeting Password . \d{4})`

Comment: no dont worry it won't,see the qsn again..:),thanks a lot for your guidance..:)

Comment: You're welcome :) If my answer turned to be helpful, you can also [mark it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).